# How to update user session from backend after updating user's metadata?

Tags: javascript, django, next.js, django-rest-framework, auth0

I´m using Next.js for the client side, auth0 to handle authentication and Django Rest Framework for the backend. Following the [Auth0's Manage Metadta Using the Management API](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-accounts/metadata/manage-metadata-api) guide, I achieved to set new metadata values (I have checked it from the Dashboard). As it is spectated, if the user refresh its profile page (`pages/profile.js`), the old session metadata is rendered.

So my question is, how can I update user session after the metadata values has been set?

I have tried to use updateSession from [@auth/nextjs-auth](https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/modules/session_update_session.html) I also  have tried [nextjs-auth0: update user session (without logging out/in) after updating user_metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74921065/nextjs-auth0-update-user-session-without-logging-out-in-after-updating-user-m/74943372#comment134901906_74943372) , but **checkSession()** is not defined so I got lost there.

**index.js**

```
   async function handleAddToFavourite() {
      if (selected) {
         const data = await axios.patch("api/updateUserSession",)
         // Update the user session for the client side
         checkSession() //this function is not defined
         
      }
   }
```

api/updateUserSession.js

```
async function handler(req, res) {

  const session = await getSession(req, res);

  if (!session || session === undefined || session === null) {
    return res.status(401).end();
  }

  const id = session?.user?.sub;
  const { accessToken } = session;

  const currentUserManagementClient = new ManagementClient({
    token: accessToken,
    domain: auth0_domain.replace('https://', ''),
    scope: process.env.AUTH0_SCOPE,
  });

  const user = await currentUserManagementClient.updateUserMetadata({ id }, req.body);
  await updateSession(req, res, { ...session, user }); // Add this to update the session

  return res.status(200).json(user);
}

export default withApiAuthRequired(handler);
```

**api/auth/[...auth0].js**

```
const afterRefetch = (req, res, session) => {
     const newSession = getSession(req, res)
     if (newSession) {
          return newSession as Promise<Session>
     }
     return session
}


export default handleAuth({
  async profile(req, res) {
    try {
      await handleProfile(req, res, {
        refetch: true,
        afterRefetch 
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
    }
  },

});
```

But I still have to log out and log in to see the new metadata values. Is there any way to update user's session from Django Rest Framework after performing the metadata update? If not, how can I update it using updateSession in Node.js?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: [Documentation?](https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/types/session_update_session.UpdateSession.html)

Answer (score 0):

As you only shared front end codes it is hard to suggest anything concrete regarding back ends.

So I am going to provide generic solutions for you.

you can check https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ ,

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/ & https://blog.devgenius.io/session-authentication-in-django-rest-framework-5e3f6fb44c59 for having better insight about working on the back end parts.